# scrollview does not scroll in second viewcontroller , but only in first home viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios

in my application i have one CameraAppViewController, from it i navigate to another view controller the OverlayViewController and from it i navigate to another view controller ScrollerViewController. I want to have a uiscrollview at the scrollerviewcontroller, but it does not scroll. However when i put the same code for uiscrollview at the first CameraAppViewController it scrolls. 
I tried all the tricks for changing the content size of the scrollview in comparison to the frame of the view , but nothing worked. I think that the code is correct since it works at the one view controller. I even tried to put it to another project and it worked to both the first and second view controllers. I would appreciate any help.

The code i use is the following:

```
UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_idv0.jpg"];
UIImage *image2=[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_idv1.jpg"];
UIImage *image3=[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_idv2.jpg"];
NSMutableArray *allImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[allImages addObject:image1];
[allImages addObject:image2];
[allImages addObject:image3];


self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];


scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;

scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
scroll.clipsToBounds = YES;

NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;


    UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[allImages objectAtIndex:i]];

    [awesomeView addSubview:imageView];

    awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
    [scroll addSubview:awesomeView];

}
```

scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.
                                height+10);

```
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

Comment: This sounds to me like you need to check your delegate connections.

Comment: I saw your edit, but it was rejected cause you should have put it in your question. Are you setting the delegate in the OverlayViewController as in: `@interface OverlayViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>`

Answer (score 0):

First do this in .h :

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Then do this in .m :

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

self.scroll.delegate = self;
```